# Executing SQL query via OracleDataReader always returns limited set of data

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell

I am trying to get some data from Oracle DB via Powershell using OracleDataReader. Things seems to be working fine except that I alwyas get a limited set of data. Say, 40 records while it returns me over 5000 with SQL manager apps. Did I miss some sort of fetch size or timeouts? How to make it throw me the whole set of data avilable?

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectionString) 
$command = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($query, $connection) 
$connection.Open() 
[System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader]$data = $command.ExecuteReader()

$Counter = $data.FieldCount
$ObjArray = @()
while ($data.Read()) { 
$Obj = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSObject
    0..($Counter - 1) | % {
                $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $data.GetName($_) -Value $data.GetValue($_)
    }
        $ObjArray += $Obj
}
$connection.Close()
return $ObjArray
```

Answer (score 0):

I would skip array creation and pass results directly to pipeline. PSObject and arrays are also prone to unwrapping. Try this solution instead (code taken from http://dev.cdur.pl/Artykuly/PowerShell-wykonywanie-polecen-SQL-Server):

```
function Invoke-Sql(
    $ConnectionString,
    $Query
) {
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($ConnectionString)
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($Query,$conn)
    $conn.Open()
    $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
    if ($reader.Read()) {
      [string[]]$columns = 0..($reader.FieldCount-1) |
          % { if ($reader.GetName($_)) { $reader.GetName($_) } else { "(no name $_)" } }
      do {
        $obj = @{}
        0..($reader.FieldCount-1) | % { $obj.Add($columns[$_], $reader[$_]) }
        [PSCustomObject]$obj
      } while ($reader.Read())
    }
    $reader.Dispose()
    $cmd.Dispose()
    $conn.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I forgot to mention that I am using Powershell v2 so that syntax would not work and yet your code would also return limited set of data, sadly.